# How to update column in one oracle table from another table without common key in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have two Oracle tables with different columns but one. I just want to update the common column of one table using the same column from another table based on the same row number like this:

table1:

```
  cst_id | item | price
 -----------------------
   10    | book | 20  
   20    | copy | 30   
   30    | pen  | 10
   25    | tea  | 14
   35    | glass| 49
```

table2:

```
   cst_id | code | color | label | age
  -------------------------------------
    110   | sss  | blue  |   R   | 10
    220   | cchh | green |   H   |  3
    330   | eee  | yellow|   J   |  5
    448   | yyy  |  -    |   U   |  4
    777   | TTT  | white |   P   |  2
    898   | RRR  |  -    |   E   |  9
    997   | GGG  |  -    |   W   |  4
```

After updating table1:

```
   cst_id | item | price
 -----------------------
    110   | book | 20  
    220   | copy | 30   
    330   | pen  | 10
    448   | tea  | 14
    777   | glass| 49
```

I use this query:

```
  MERGE INTO table1 t1
  USING (
  SELECT cst_id, ROWID as rid
   FROM (
    SELECT cst_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY age) AS rn
    FROM table2
   ) t2
  ) t2
 ON (t1.ROWID = t2.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET t1.cst_id = t2.cst_id;
```

But the result is *0 row merge*.

Would you please guide what another way is for this update?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, with out any column it will be difficult to update, how many rows are present in both the table if there are very small you can update  table1 by writing an individual update statement.  Do you know if there is any relation between cst_id in table1 and table2 ?

Comment: This isn't reasonable. Relational data does not have "row order" at rest in a table. You could abritrarily assign order at query time, but that's going to be meaningless. The only way you'd pull this off is if there is a data column that you can order by and that can be meaningfully used to associate rows in this way. But in all likelihood, you have unrelatable data here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theoretical result you present is not correlated to the query you wrote:
if you order table2 by age, the first row will be the 777 one and thus the result will be "777   | book | 20" not what you present.
You will not be able to do it in SQL with MERGE (error you can get is "ORA-01445: Cannot Select ROWID from a Join View without a Key-Preserved Table") but in PL/SQL you can do:

```
begin
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT t2.cst_id, t2.rn, t1.rid FROM 
            (SELECT cst_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY age) AS rn FROM table2) t2
          JOIN (SELECT rowid AS rid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cst_id) AS rn FROM table1) t1  
          ON t1.rn = t2.rn
    )
    LOOP
        UPDATE table1 SET cst_id = rec.cst_id
        WHERE rowid = rec.rid;
    END LOOP ;
end ;
```

And the result will be:

```
777 book    20
220 copy    30
997 pen 10
448 tea 14
330 glass   49
```

Comment: as I said the sample that I wrote, is not related to the query. The query did not run correctly. But, the sample shows what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

[ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-F6E0FBD2-983C-495D-9856-5E113A17FAF1) is unique for every row in the database. No two rows will have the same ROWID. So your comparison of `t1.ROWID = t2.rid` is guaranteed to fail, unless you're joining a table to itself.

Perhaps there are other tables in your database that could provide additional information, but given the data you've presented I see no way to obtain the results you want.